# How to increase autocomplete performance

Tags: sql-server

We are working on a website like www.justdial.com . 
We want to provide AutoComplete feature.

This autocomplete feature should be inline with the performance of justdial's.

We are using Indexes, please suggest more ways to provide superfast autocompletion.

Comment: +1, you mean just like google search auto complete?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best proven ways to improve search performance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6574572/best-proven-ways-to-improve-search-performance).  Rather than post a new question, you could refine the previous one.

Comment: I chose to post diff questions because these are two diff scenarios, and I have seen asking poster to post diff questions for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

I do not have much experience in the subject, but I have just implemented JQuery autocomplete with a medium sized list ~(1,000) entries, partial matches is enabled and it is still astoundingly fast. The only trick I've used is creating seperate js files for the lists and calling them first from the html. I also refrain from using the jquery on ready, so the complete list is bieng uploaded immediately. The actual calls to autocomplete are done on page ready.  [JQuery AutoComplete](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/autocomplete)

Unfortunately I can't add the actual code because the data is sensitive, but its on the lines of..

```
<html>
  <body>
    Some HTML
    <script type = "text/javascript" src = "collection.js"></script>
    <script type = "text/javascript" src = "jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type = "text/javascript" src = "autocomplete.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Collection .js would look something like

```
var collection = ["1","2","3", ... "1000"];
```

and AutoComplete.js would look like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#form").autocomplete(collection, { matchContains:true });
});
```

I don't know what built in optimization Jquery has,but it seems pretty fast to me.

I believe even the Google "Suggest" feature used javascript, so it would just be a matter of keeping the lists sorted and dividing them efficiently? Maybe [Huffman Coding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding) could help?

Comment: thousands of users posting thousands of diff. criteria. data is not static.

Comment: I've found limitations of about 40,000 items for the inline Javascript collection.  After that, you need to server side impl.